# Comparing file size with existing value

Tags: c#, foreach, filenames, filesize

I want to check filename and its associated filesize with the help of a foreach loop. So I have the below 2 string arrays containing file name and file size:

```
string[] file_name = {
    "file1.dll",
    "file2.dll"
};
string[] file_size = {
    "17662", //file1.dll size
    "19019" //file2.dll size
};
```

And with below foreach loops I am checking  the file and size are matching

```
foreach (string filename in file_name)
        {
            foreach (string filesize in file_size)
            {
                if (File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dll\\" + filename))
                {
                    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dll\\" + filename);
                    string s1 = f.Length.ToString();
                    if (s1 != filesize)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(f.Name + "modified DLL file, please change it to original");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But it always shows the message, I don't know where is the error.

Comment: The problem is quite simple. You are comparing both files to both sizes…
You could create a Dictionary<String, Int32> (Filename as key, Size as value) and then loop over the dictionary and compare the value to the size of the file.

Comment: Heh @musium, thanks for your answer, but I'm newbie, can you give me example link, or write example/full code? :(

Comment: Why are you using two separate arrays for file size and name?

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid, I'm metioned that I'm newbie, and i need help, not question :(

Comment: @EvaldasL I’ve posted an example of working with dictionaries in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you to use generic dictionary.

```
        //Create a dictionary that holds the file name with it's size
        Dictionary<string, long> FileNameAndSizes = new Dictionary<string, long>();

        //Key of dictionary will contain file name
        //Value of dictionary will contain file size
        FileNameAndSizes.Add("file1.dll", 17662);
        FileNameAndSizes.Add("file2.dll", 19019);

        //Iterate through the dictionary
        foreach (var item in FileNameAndSizes)
        {
            //Look for file existance
            if (File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dll\\" + item.Key))
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dll\\" + item.Key);
                var s1 = f.Length;

                //Compare the current file size with stored size
                if (s1 != item.Value)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(f.Name + "modified DLL file, please change it to original");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would suggest the dictionary should be type of Dictionary<string, int>.

Comment: @AnupamSharma: thanks for pointing out. Edited to make if long, in sync with the file info length

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simple as

Create new class as
MyFiles.cs

```
public class MyFiles
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long Size { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set;}
    }
    public class MyWorkClass
    {
        private void InputFiles()
        {
            var files = new List<MyFiles>();
            var file = new MyFiles { Name = "File1.dll", Size = 1215454 };
            files.Add(file);
            file = new MyFiles { Name = "File2.dll", Size = 15544 };
            files.Add(file);
            ProcessFile(files);
        }

        private void ProcessFile(List<MyFiles> files)
        {
            foreach (MyFiles file in files)
            {
                var name = file.Name;
                var size = file.Size;
                //Do other things
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For a static list (and I assume it is), that requires quite a bit of extra code.

Comment: @PMF I give him an example, I don't know how he is putting data into arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I won’t write the full code for you.. this is your job^^
But I’ll help you.

You have to do something like this:

```
public void Test()
{
    //Use filename as key and file size as value
    var files = new Dictionary<String, Int32>
    {
        { "file1.dll", 17662 },
        { "file2.dll", 19019 }
    };

    foreach ( var file in files )
    {
        //..get filesize name is stored in file.Key
        if(fielsize != file.Value)
            //display error message
    }
}
```

1)  Store the filenames and the filesize in a dictionary see: [for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

2)  Get the size of each file using your code and compare the size with the value of the key-value-pair.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like

```
Dictionary<string,int> files = new Dictionary<string, int>() { {"file1.dll", 12345}, {"file2.dll", 34566} };
```

then you can iterate with just one loop:

```
foreach (var entry in files) // type of entry is "KeyValuePair<string,int>"
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "dll",  entry.Key)))
        { 
             // Compare file size against entry.Value here.
             // ...
        }
    }
}
```

A dictionary is a data structure that stores a value for each key. Both keys and values can be (almost) of any type.

Besides: Never use the + operator to concatenate paths. Use Path.Combine instead.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is you are comparing both files names with both file size.

```
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, file_name.Length))
        {
            string filename = file_name[i];
            string filesize = file_size[i];

            if (File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dll\\" + filename))
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dll\\" + filename);
                string s1 = f.Length.ToString();
                if (s1 != filesize)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(f.Name + "modified DLL file, please change it to original");
                }
            }
        }
```